# Close navigation menu if page link is clicked

Tags: css, angular, sass, navigation

In my Angular 8 application, a fixed navigation bar exists on top of the screen. When a user hovers over a dropdown nav link, a menu will show up.

Now, if the user clicks on one of the menu links, the corresponding page will be opened using Angular Routing:

```html
<div class="nav-left">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <a class="menu" routerLink="/home">
      {{'HOME.TITLE' | translate}}
      <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-angle-down"></i></span>
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a routerLink="/home/welcome">
        <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i></span>
        {{'HOME.TITLE' | translate}}
      </a>
      <a routerLink="/home/news-blog">
        <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-newspaper-o"></i></span>
        {{'HOME.NEWS_BLOG' | translate}}
      </a>
      <a routerLink="/home/features">
        <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-cubes"></i></span>
        {{'HOME.FEATURES' | translate}}
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My SCSS definition has a `.dropdown:hover` selector that shows a menu only if it is hovered:

```css
.dropdown {
  .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
  }

  &:hover {
    .dropdown-content {
      display: block;
    }
  }
}
```

**What I would like to achieve** is that the navigation menu closes automatically when the user clicks a menu link. Right now, the menu remains open because Angular Router does not reload the page but only replaces the page contents by the selected subpage.

In my opinion, there should be a pure CSS / SCSS solution to this problem, although it would be okay for me if it only works with some TypeScript code. My ideas have been so far:

- use a special "click" or "selected" CSS selector to define `display: none` if a link has been clicked
- activate some Angular function (if exists?) that resets the "CSS state" (as if the page would have been reloaded)
- write a method to close all navigation menus when a `routerLink` has been clicked (seems too complicated)

Do you have any recommendations which of the mentioned approaches would fit best and how to realize it?

Comment: Do u have a codepen or fiddle?

Comment: As opposed to using a CSS hover, you could use a class to define the menu as open, and have a listener in your Angular code (reacting to mouseover, for example, using event binding in the template) which adds and removes it using `[ngClass]`. Do you get the idea?

Comment: @WillAlexander Yes, I think that would be worth a try. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have a listener in your template along the lines of:

```html
<div class="dropdown" [ngClass]="{'visible': menuVisible}" (mouseover)="toggleMenu()" (mouseout)="toggleMenu()">
```

And in your TS:

```js
menuVisible = false;
toggleMenu() {
  this.menuVisible = !this.menuVisible;
}
```

This would be a very simple implementation. You could also do it using Observables, for example (having a Subject emit for each mouse event).

EDIT: I totally forgot to add the click listener part haha! I think you got the idea though!